# can anyone tell me ,how to use image in a flat-list of react-native?

Tags: react-native

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            list: []
        };
    }

    getList = () => {
        const li = [
            { key: "image1", imagelink: "" },
            { key: "image2", imgLink: "imagelink" },
            { key: "image3", imgLink: "imagelink" },
            { key: "image3", imgLink: "imagelink" },
        ]

        this.setState({
            list: li
        })
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getList()
    }

    render() {
        return (
export default App;
```

Comment: Please, rewrite your question !

Comment: Hai Guys,I am new to react-native ,can anyone send me a code of "how to set images side by side by using flatlist"

Answer (score 1):

You could just google it, but here is an example:

use `FlatList` for the list. Pass it the data and a render function.

```
<FlatList
   data={this.data}
   renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderItem(item, index)}
/>
```

then create the render function in your component:

```
renderItem(item, index) {
    return (
        <Image source={{uri: item.image}}/>
    )
}
```

as an example the data is a component variable:

```
data = [{image: "link"}, {image: "link"}]
```

Comment: yes, i already google it!but I'm not getting proper answer!could you please send me a code

Comment: @Kartiikeya well, I found some examples within 30 seconds. And this above is an example. Just copy it into a component and it will work. Of course replace the links with real ones. Also place the FlatList in the render method.